# Python / VTK script crashes in windows when application window is opened or moved resulting in Spyder kernel crash

Tags: spyder, vtk, python-3.8

Python 3.8.5
VTK 9.0.1
Spyder 4.1.5
Windows 10 Home (new installation)

The following (borrowed) script produces a cone like object rotating through 360 degrees - or it should :

```
import vtk
import time

cone = vtk.vtkConeSource()

mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(cone.GetOutputPort())

actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderer.ResetCamera()
camera = renderer.GetActiveCamera()

window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
window.AddRenderer(renderer)

azimuth = 0
while 1:
    window.Render()
    if azimuth >= 360:
        azimuth = 0
    azimuth += 0.1
    camera.Azimuth(azimuth)

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

on Run a new window is created but minimised in the tool bar only (white rectangle).

If I leave the new window as an icon in the toolbar but hold the mouse over I get to see the cone rotating as it should. However if I open the window by clicking the mouse on it it opens with the cone frozen and eventually the kernel crashes with the message :

[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: f7a8b494237011ebb6f90c8bfdf07845 with different hex value each time.

If I run the same script directly in a CMD window the window opens fully and the cone rotates as it should with no subsequent kernel crash. If, however, I then move the window the cone stops and the kernel crashes with no visible message.

So the problem seems to be related to the subsequent movement of the window on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar issue from a couple of years ago under python 2.7 using paraview :

[Render() causes a non responding window](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/render-causes-a-non-responding-visualization-toolkit-win32opengl-on-windows/538)

This lead me to re-write my script using an interactor :

```
import vtk
import time
import sys

class vtkTimerCallback():
   def __init__(self):
       self.timer_count = 0
       self.Azimuth = 0
       

   def execute(self,obj,event):
       iren = obj
       iren.GetRenderWindow().Render()
    
       if self.Azimuth >= 360:
           self.Azimuth = 0

       self.Azimuth += 0.1
       camera.Azimuth(self.Azimuth)
               
cone = vtk.vtkConeSource()

mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(cone.GetOutputPort())

actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderer.ResetCamera()
camera = renderer.GetActiveCamera()

window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
window.SetSize(600,600)
window.AddRenderer(renderer)

istyle = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleSwitch()
istyle.SetCurrentStyleToTrackballCamera()

interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(window)
interactor.SetInteractorStyle(istyle)

interactor.Initialize()
```

and Bingo it works fine - with the added fun of being able to re position the rotating cone with your mouse.

So workaround in place - love to know the reason why ...